# Start position in text box (html/css)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a text box, so the user can enter a chapter of a book into that.

It's starting to type from the middle of a box. how can I fix it?

[image]

```css
.TextBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #cccccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.TextBox > h1 {
  font-family: 'Consolas';
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#textbox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="TextBox">
    <h1> Enter text here </h1>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="textbox">
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `textarea` instead of `input` box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<textarea>` and align it, if I undestood you correctly, to the center. With the `col` attribute you can define the width of the textarea and with the `row` you can define the height of the textarea

```css
.TextBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #cccccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.TextBox > h1 {
  font-family: 'Consolas';
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#textbox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="TextBox">
    <h1> Enter text here </h1>
    <form>
      <textarea cols="80" rows="10" id="textbox" type="text" name="textbox">Lorem ipsum
</textarea>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a `textarea`.

Take a look here:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/byznwzra/

Answer (score 0):

Try with textarea :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="TextBox">
            <h1> Enter text here </h1>
            <form> <textarea type="text" id="textbox" ></textarea>   </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32w248ta/)

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to have something like this below (When I change the Text in `TextArea` then text in `Heading` will be changed).

Please check below fiddle, and let me know.

```js
function changeHead()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("txtarea").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
.TextBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #cccccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.TextBox > h1 {
  font-family: 'Consolas';
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#txtarea {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="TextBox">
    <h1 id="demo"> Enter text here </h1>
    <form>
      <textarea id="txtarea" cols="52" rows="6" id="textbox" type="text" name="textbox" onkeypress="changeHead()" placeholder="Enter Text Here">
</textarea>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```